# Trying to pull 2 fields when using MIN(CASE when... or MAX(CASE when

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the min/max score and I also need the date these scores were taken. Any ideas on how to do this using Oracle SQL? Here is the full code that works and gives me the students name, etc, and the min scores and 1 max score:

```
SELECT s.lastfirst, s.state_studentnumber, s.grade_level, s.schoolid, 
MIN(case when ts.name='ACT_English' then sts.numscore else null end) ACT_English, 
MIN(case when ts.name='ACT_Reading' then sts.numscore else null end) ACT_Reading, 
MIN(case when ts.name='ACT_Math' then sts.numscore else null end) ACT_Math, 
MIN(case when ts.name='ACT_Science' then sts.numscore else null end) ACT_Science, 
MAX(case when ts.name='ACT_Composite' then sts.numscore else null end) ACT_Composite
FROM studenttestscore sts
INNER JOIN students s
ON sts.studentid=s.id
INNER JOIN studenttest st
ON sts.studenttestid=st.id
INNER JOIN testscore ts
ON sts.testscoreid=ts.id
INNER JOIN test t
ON ts.testid=t.id
WHERE t.name='ACT' AND s.enroll_status=0 and s.schoolid = 32
GROUP BY s.lastfirst, s.state_studentnumber, s.grade_level, s.schoolid
ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

The date field is in the studenttest table (st.test_date).
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just FYI, you can omit `else null` in `CASE` statements.

Comment: It would probably help to know the structure of your tables

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli Here is sample table structures: students table has these fields: lastfirst, student_number, id. studenttestscore table has studentid (linked to students.id), numscore, studenttestid, testscoreid. studenttest table has id (linked to studenttestscore.studenttestid), test_date. testscore table has id (linked to studenttestscore.studenttestid), name, testid. test table has id (linked to testscore.testid), name. It's complicated, I know, but this is how PowerSchool has it setup, no control there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you are using Oracle.  Then you can use `keep`, the general format is:

```
select . . .,
       max(date) keep (dense_rank first order by sts.numscore desc)
```

This is a little trickier for filtering.  One method uses two case expressions:

```
select . . .,
       max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_English' then date end) keep
           (dense_rank first order by (case when t.name = 'ACT_English' then 1 else 2 end), sts.numscore desc)
           )
```

Comment: Here is sample table structures:

Comment: Sorry, hit enter before I was finished... Here is sample table structures: students table has these fields: lastfirst, student_number, id. studenttestscore table has studentid (linked to students.id), numscore, studenttestid, testscoreid. studenttest table has id (linked to studenttestscore.studenttestid), test_date. testscore table has id (linked to studenttestscore.studenttestid), name, testid. test table has id (linked to testscore.testid), name.  It's complicated, I know, but this is how PowerSchool has it setup, no control there...

Comment: Thanks @Gordon-Linoff I got it working with your suggestions.